# creating a simple Login page to login and redirect to a page not working ot..!

Tags: php, forms, apache, authentication, centos7

so i am trying to create a simple small login system, nothing complicated here no register, insert to db, etc. a index.php form which sends the POST data to a login.php file which will the if the logic is satisfied redirect to a welcome.php

my index.php looks like:

```
<title> The Game </title>
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 200px auto 0 auto;">
<div class="imgcontainer">
<h1> The </h1>
<img src="gamep.jpg" alt="Game">
</div>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<p style="font-size: 150%;"> Username: </p> <input type="text" 
name="username" /> <br /> 
<p style="font-size: 150%;"> Password: </p> <input type="password" 
 name="password" /> <br />
<br/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="login" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; left: 
   250; top: 250; "/>
       </form>
     </div>
```

and my login page looks like

```
 <?php
  $error='';
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
      }
     else
        {

        $username=$_POST['username'];
         $password=$_POST['password'];

          $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost. "root", "");

             $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "users");

              $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
             username= '$username' AND password= '$password');

             $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                   if($rows == 1){
                 header("Location: welcome.php");
                     }
                     else
                       {
                      $error = "Username of password is invalid";
                     }
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                       }
                       }
                       ?>
```

and my welcome page is

```
                   class="imgcontainer">
                 <img src="gamep.jpg" alt="Game">
                       </div>
```

i cant understand where i am going wrong, i would deduce till here learning from youtube tutorials... and my database has only 1 value in it..i am on centosVM running httpd and mariadb...restart the httpd everytime...still no good..!!

the index page just redirects to a blank login page ..please help me i have limited time to work on this!!!!

Comment: Do you closed the double quotes?? Check the line
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
             username= '$username' AND password= '$password');

Comment: "localhost. "   why the dot after localhost  and missing to close double quotes ?

Comment: your database name is "users" is correct ? i think it's table is it ?

Comment: try my answer @Mahesh Chandra

Comment: i fixed the missing double quote and the "Localhost." typos.. and yes users is my database and the table in the database is also users.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your submit button does not have any name. So `isset($_POST['submit'])` always return false. change the following

```
<input type="submit" value="login" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; left: 
   250; top: 250; "/>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; left: 
   250; top: 250; "/>
```

Secondly, you are not connect the mysqli properly. see [how to connect this properly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

1) input submit element name missing

```
<input type="submit" value="login" name="submit" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; left:250; top: 250; "/>
```

2) your code have lot's of double quotes closing problem and lot's of typo error .

3) Don't use user input directly into sql query . it cause sql injection possibilities . so try to use prepared statement or pdo to avoid sql injection like this

```
`   <?php
      $error='';
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
          }
         else
            {

            $username=$_POST['username'];
             $password=$_POST['password'];

              $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

                 $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "users") or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

                  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
                  $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
                 // The argument may be one of four types:

                    //i - integer
                    //d - double
                    //s - string
                    //b - BLOB
                    //change it by respectively 
                  $stmt->execute();
                  $rows= $stmt->affected_rows;
                  $stmt->close();
                  $conn->close();
                       if($rows>0)
                       {
                            header("Location: welcome.php");
                       }
                        else
                        {
                             $error = "Username of password is invalid";
                        }
            }
      }

                           ?>`
```

Comment: nope not working tried this code exactly..copy paste ..just to be sure checked all the open ports ..nope not working it redirects to the php page but shows the code of the php instead..

Comment: did have installed apache ?

Comment: yeah i have httpd & mariadb in centos

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This may help.

```
<?php
  $error='';
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
       $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {

      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];



    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database name');
if(!conn){
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
else
{
          $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "users");

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$username' AND password= '$password'");

      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($rows == 1){
          header("Location: welcome.php");
      }
      else
      {
           $error = "Username of password is invalid";
      }
}
          mysqli_close($conn);
      }



}
   ?>
```

And

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" style="height: 50px; width: 100px; left: 
   250; top: 250; "/>
```

Comment: i tried using your code and replaced the username,password and the database but i still run into the same error..!!